# jQuery mobile Rails thumbnails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mobile

I want to create a list with thumbnails, a text description and a number count.

My _ele.html.erb looks like this:

```
<li>

          <img src="http://www.starbucks.com/static/images/global/logo.png" alt="some_text"/>
          <%= link_to "#{user.name}", user_path(user), "data-icon" => "gear"%>
          <span class="ui-li-count" >5</span>

</li>
```

What it looks like right now is a picture, and underneath it is the user.name

I want it so that user.name appears to the right of image.

How do I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you check the demo here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html ?
You basically need a structure like this:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview">
     <li><a href="index.html">
       <img src="http://www.starbucks.com/static/images/global/logo.png" />
       <span><%= link_to "#{user.name}", user_path(user), "data-icon" => "gear"%></span>
       <span class="ui-li-count">5</span>
     </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just copied from the example - just remove the <a> tag or exchange link target.